# Can magnets induce magnetism stronger then their own magnetism?

Tags: magnetic-fields, induction

This might sound foolish but bear with me for the explanation.

I came across a weird magnetic behaviour playing with coins on a mac. There are magnets in mac, two on the top corners of the screen and two on the hand-rest areas.
I observed two things:
If you make a coin vertically stand on the magnet and then make another one stand on the first coin, you can feel the magnetic attraction between the 3 bodies. The astounding thing is that you can lift the top coin and the bottom coin will stick to it and come along with it. The middle coin is being pulled by the mac magnet plus gravity while it is pulled above by just the induced magnetism of the second coin. How is this possible?

Second observation: The magnets on the screen feel way stronger than those at the hand-rest. But when the coins are placed similarly on the screen magnets, the top coin hardly feels any attraction to the bottom coin, let alone lifting it up. Why would this difference between the stronger and the week magnet be?

Note:
The coins being used are Indian 2 Rupee coins.
Metal : Ferratic Stainless Steel, Weight : 5.62 gms, Diameter : 27 mm